# effective counting of objects

Tags: database, django, query-optimization

I have 2 models:

```
Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    no_of_posts = models.IntegerField(default=0) # a denormalised field to store post count

Post(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    desc = models.TextField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)  
    first_save = models.BooleanField()
```

Since I always want to show the no. of posts alongwith each category, I always count & store them every time a user creates or deletes a post this way:

```
   ## inside Post model ##
   def save(self):  
      if not pub_date and first_save:
        pub_date = datetime.datetime.now()
        # counting & saving category posts when a post is 1st published
        category = self.category
        super(Post, self).save()
        category.no_of_posts = Post.objects.filter(category=category).count()
        category.save()

   def delete(self): 
        category = self.category
        super(Post, self).delete()
        category.no_of_posts = Post.objects.filter(category=category).count()
        category.save()
        ........
```

My question is whether, instead of counting every object, can we not use something like:

```
 category.no_of_posts += 1 // in save() # and
 category.no_of_posts -= 1 // in delete()
```

**Or is there a better solution!**

*Oh, I missed that! I updated the post model to include the relationship!*

Comment: I am using `no_of_posts` field to get rid of querying the database (counting objects) everytime I want to list the no. of posts in categories.  
 
I think it would be rather better to store the counts in the database by figuring out the appropriate instances of counting & storing.  

This way we don't need to count the objects everytime a listing is required.  

**A lot less load on the database!!**

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a much better solution:

```
from django.db.models import Count

class CategoryManager(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self, *args, **kwargs):
        qs = super(CategoryManager, self).get_query_set(*args, **kwargs)
        return qs.annotate(no_of_posts=Count('post'))

class Category(models.Model):
    ...
    objects = CategoryManager()
```

Since you didn't show the relationship between Post and Category, I guessed on the `Count('posts')` part. You might have to fiddle with that.

Oh, and you'll want to get rid of the `no_of_posts` field from the model. It's not necessary with this. Or, you can just change the name of the annotation.

You'll still be able to get the post count with `category.no_of_posts` but you're making the database do the legwork for you.